# AJAX/UpdatePanel not working on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I got a simple ASP.NET UpdatePanel, which works as expected when I run it Visual Studio (Casini).

However, once deployed to my local IIS, it’s not working anymore.

What’s misconfigured?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

... and the codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Presentation.Web
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In Casini, the label is updated without a postback. On IIS, a postback occurs.

Comment: Any errors? Is it postback the page?

Comment: u getting error 'Sys is undefined'

Comment: The page does a regular postback when hosted on IIS. In Casini it does the AJAX request as expected.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a 'Sys is not defined' (didn't notice it until now).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in the Handlers section in the web.config file:

`<add name="Ajax" verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax"/>`

Comment: Didn't help, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET AJAX requires web pages to be XHTML compatible (not HTML 4.0).  In fact, not having the mode=Transitional in the web.config will stop the scriptManager from even getting rendered in the page, and every AJAX hit would act like a regular postback.

put in web.config xhtmlConformance mode="Transitional"/>

[Chk link it should help u](http://weblogs.asp.net/varadam/archive/2011/03/22/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-sys-is-undefined.aspx)

Comment: Didn't help, still the same problem.